# How to make Glade load translations from /opt

Tags: python, application-development, glade, gettext, localization

I've created an application that I'd like to submit through the [Ubuntu app developer process](https://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/). One of the requirements for the process is that when installed, all files go into the `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/<appname>` directory.

Through changes in packaging and with help from others I've achieved that, but now I'm facing a new problem: when running from `/opt` the translations from my app are not being loaded.

What happens is the following: unless specified otherwise, the binary files (MO files) containing translations for an application are loaded from `/usr/share/locale` (or in the case of Ubuntu, from `/usr/share/locale-langpack`), but in my app, due to the `/opt` requirement, they are installed in `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/qreator/locale`.

That's in theory fine, as [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html) allows specifying an alternative location to load translations, so I add the [`bindtextdomain`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#gettext.bindtextdomain) call to achieve that:

```
import gettext
from gettext import gettext as _
gettext.bindtextdomain('qreator', '/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/qreator/share/locale/')
gettext.textdomain('qreator')
```

That works well up to a point: all messages that are output on the command line then appear translated as expected. But **it does not solve the main problem**: to load the translations from the UI Glade requires specifying the translation domain once more (the equivalent to the `gettext.textdomain('qreator')` call above), but it does not let specifying where to load translations from (i.e. the Glade equivalent to `bindtextdomain`, which sadly does not exist). Here's an extract of the code that I'm using:

```
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.set_translation_domain('qreator')
# There isn't a way to tell glade to load translations from
# somewhere else than /usr/share/locale here
builder.add_from_file(ui_filename)
```

This essentially means that translations from the UI cannot be loaded if your app is installed in `/opt`.

I'm pretty much stuck at this point. Any ideas on how to make Glade load translations from `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/qreator/share/locale/` instead of `/usr/share/locale`?

Comment: After talking to someone more knowledgeable on Gtk.Builder, I've filed a bug: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676543

Comment: I've also been pointed out to a workaround, but it did not seem to work for me - here it is: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=114461#12

Comment: Could you include a full minimal runnable example in your python code?  I'm happy to drill down into this, but I'm not sure what imports I'm missing to get a Gtk.Builder().

Comment: n/m, apparently that's just 'import gtk' ;)

Comment: @slangasek,it's `from gi.repository import Gtk`, but there's a runnable minimal example attached to the bug report I filed on the first comment.

Comment: right - I give up, there seems to be no sane way to get gettext.bindtextdomain() to take hold for glade :/

Comment: Bummer, that's a major blocker if we cannot ship localized apps in our app developer process :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found a solution: use the *locale* Python module instead of *gettext*

```
import locale
from locale import gettext as _
locale.bindtextdomain('qreator', '/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/qreator/share/locale/')
locale.textdomain('qreator')
```

Thanks to Juha Sahakangas on the #gtk+ IRC channel for providing the explanation:

> For this particular case the [locale](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#access-to-message-catalogs) module needs to be used
>   instead of [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html). Python's *gettext* module is pure python, it
>   doesn't actually set the text domain in a way that the C library can
>   read, but *locale* does (by calling libc). So long as that's done,
>   GtkBuilder already works the way you're asking it to.